# Why does ArcGIS for Desktop legend not always show symbol as desired?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, symbology, legend, layouts

I have a problem with the legends in the ArcMap because the patch does not show the marker symbol inside it well.

Whenever, I move the legend it changes but never to what I want for every patch.

I have tried legend properties, and so on but nothing helped me.

You can see my legend **[here](http://postimg.org/image/47cs4jzdt/)**.

Comment: i opened the shape in gis 10.2(point), i want to change the symbol of it but the symbols don't show normally,

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! The answer function is meant exclusively for answering questions and not asking your own question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/106413)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/106413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect that you are after I think you will need to experiment with static legends which you can create using **[Convert To Graphics on the Legend Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000)**.

> You might want to convert a map element, such as a legend, to graphics
>   if you want more precise control over each item that composes the map
>   element.

Do the patches without marker/text and then use the **Draw** toolbar to centre the text/marker in each taking care to match the size, font, etc.

Comment: ok. i tried convert to graphics but not satisfactory, with the draw toolbar, its perfect, i delete the legend patch, and place the markers with the mencioned toolbar. thanx Polygeo.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... how do you stop Arc from doing this?

Comment: @TomW As far as I know you cannot so raising an  ArcGIS Idea may be your only way forward if you need this. Targeting ArcGIS Pro may be more fruitful.